# Combine framework retry after delay?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I see how to use `.retry` directly, to resubscribe after an error, like this:

```
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for:url)
        .retry(3)
```

But that seems awfully simple-minded. What if I think that this error might go away if I wait awhile? I could insert a `.delay` operator, but then the delay operates even if there is no error. And there doesn't seem to be a way to apply an operator conditionally (i.e. only when there's an error).

I see how I could work around this by writing a RetryWithDelay operator from scratch, and indeed such an operator has been written by third parties. But is there a way to say "delay if there's an error", purely using the operators we're given?

My thought was that I could use `.catch`, because its function runs only if there is an error. But the function needs to return a publisher, and what publisher would we use? If we return `somePublisher.delay(...)` followed by `.retry`, we'd be applying `.retry` to the wrong publisher, wouldn't we?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was a topic of conversation on the [Using Combine](https://gum.co/usingcombine) project repo a while back - the whole thread: https://github.com/heckj/swiftui-notes/issues/164.

The long and short was we made an example that I think does what you want, although it does use `catch`:

```swift
let resultPublisher = upstreamPublisher.catch { error -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> in
    return Publishers.Delay(upstream: upstreamPublisher,
                            interval: 3,
                            tolerance: 1,
                            scheduler: DispatchQueue.global())
    // moving retry into this block reduces the number of duplicate requests
    // In effect, there's the original request, and the `retry(2)` here will operate
    // two additional retries on the otherwise one-shot publisher that is initiated with
    // the `Publishers.Delay()` just above. Just starting this publisher with delay makes
    // an additional request, so the total number of requests ends up being 4 (assuming all
    // fail). However, no delay is introduced in this sequence if the original request
    // is successful.
    .retry(2)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

This is referencing the a [retry pattern I have in the book/online](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#patterns-retry), which is basically what you describe (but wasn't what you asked about).

The [person I was corresponding with on the issue](https://github.com/anechaev) provided a variant in that thread as an extension that might be interesting as well:

```swift
extension Publisher {
  func retryWithDelay<T, E>()
    -> Publishers.Catch<Self, AnyPublisher<T, E>> where T == Self.Output, E == Self.Failure
  {
    return self.catch { error -> AnyPublisher<T, E> in
      return Publishers.Delay(
        upstream: self,
        interval: 3,
        tolerance: 1,
        scheduler: DispatchQueue.global()).retry(2).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, so it turns out there is no need for a custom operator; it suffices to make a reference to the original upstream publisher and `share` it and use it twice.

Comment: @matt while I agree that sharing the upstream publisher will suffice, having a custom operator makes the code simpler, cleaner, and more maintainable. I would go with the custom operator instead of having all that boilerplate every time I want to do something like this.

Comment: The extension is a nice approach for this.

Comment: It's incorrect because the delay delays the events, not the subscription. As a result the first retry will be executed immediately after the first failure. The result of the retry will be delayed by 3 seconds which is not what you want.

Answer (score 14):

I found a few quirks with the implementations in the accepted answer.

- Firstly the first two attempts will be fired off without a delay since the first delay will only take effect after the second attempt.
- Secondly if any one of the retry attempts succeed, the output value will also delayed which seems unnecessary.
- Thirdly the extension is not flexible enough to allow the user to decide which scheduler it would like the retry attempts to be dispatched to.

After some tinkering back and forth I ended up with a solution like this:

```swift
public extension Publisher {
    /**
     Creates a new publisher which will upon failure retry the upstream publisher a provided number of times, with the provided delay between retry attempts.
     If the upstream publisher succeeds the first time this is bypassed and proceeds as normal.

     - Parameters:
        - retries: The number of times to retry the upstream publisher.
        - delay: Delay in seconds between retry attempts.
        - scheduler: The scheduler to dispatch the delayed events.

     - Returns: A new publisher which will retry the upstream publisher with a delay upon failure.

     ~~~
     let url = URL(string: "https://api.myService.com")!

     URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
         .retryWithDelay(retries: 4, delay: 5, scheduler: DispatchQueue.global())
         .sink { completion in
             switch completion {
             case .finished:
                 print("Success ")
             case .failure(let error):
                 print("The last and final failure after retry attempts: \(error)")
             }
         } receiveValue: { output in
             print("Received value: \(output)")
         }
         .store(in: &cancellables)
     ~~~
     */
    func retryWithDelay<S>(
        retries: Int,
        delay: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride,
        scheduler: S
    ) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> where S: Scheduler {
        self
            .delayIfFailure(for: delay, scheduler: scheduler)
            .retry(retries)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    private func delayIfFailure<S>(
        for delay: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride,
        scheduler: S
    ) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> where S: Scheduler {
        self.catch { error in
            Future { completion in
                scheduler.schedule(after: scheduler.now.advanced(by: delay)) {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for thinking about this!

Comment: What about a publisher that conditionally retries the request?

Answer (score 6):

I remembered that the [RxSwiftExt](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt) library had a really nice implementation of a custom retry + delay operator with many options (linear and exponential delay, plus an option to provide a custom closure) and I tried to recreate it in Combine. The original implementation is [here](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt/blob/main/Source/RxSwift/retryWithBehavior.swift).

```
/**
 Provides the retry behavior that will be used - the number of retries and the delay between two subsequent retries.
 - `.immediate`: It will immediatelly retry for the specified retry count
 - `.delayed`: It will retry for the specified retry count, adding a fixed delay between each retry
 - `.exponentialDelayed`: It will retry for the specified retry count.
 The delay will be incremented by the provided multiplier after each iteration
 (`multiplier = 0.5` corresponds to 50% increase in time between each retry)
 - `.custom`: It will retry for the specified retry count. The delay will be calculated by the provided custom closure.
 The closure's argument is the current retry
 */
enum RetryBehavior<S> where S: Scheduler {
  case immediate(retries: UInt)
  case delayed(retries: UInt, time: TimeInterval)
  case exponentialDelayed(retries: UInt, initial: TimeInterval, multiplier: Double)
  case custom(retries: UInt, delayCalculator: (UInt) -> TimeInterval)
}

fileprivate extension RetryBehavior {
  
  func calculateConditions(_ currentRetry: UInt) -> (maxRetries: UInt, delay: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride) {
    
    switch self {
    case let .immediate(retries):
      // If immediate, returns 0.0 for delay
      return (maxRetries: retries, delay: .zero)
    case let .delayed(retries, time):
      // Returns the fixed delay specified by the user
      return (maxRetries: retries, delay: .seconds(time))
    case let .exponentialDelayed(retries, initial, multiplier):
      // If it is the first retry the initial delay is used, otherwise it is calculated
      let delay = currentRetry == 1 ? initial : initial * pow(1 + multiplier, Double(currentRetry - 1))
      return (maxRetries: retries, delay: .seconds(delay))
    case let .custom(retries, delayCalculator):
      // Calculates the delay with the custom calculator
      return (maxRetries: retries, delay: .seconds(delayCalculator(currentRetry)))
    }
    
  }
  
}

public typealias RetryPredicate = (Error) -> Bool

extension Publisher {
  /**
   Retries the failed upstream publisher using the given retry behavior.
   - parameter behavior: The retry behavior that will be used in case of an error.
   - parameter shouldRetry: An optional custom closure which uses the downstream error to determine
   if the publisher should retry.
   - parameter tolerance: The allowed tolerance in firing delayed events.
   - parameter scheduler: The scheduler that will be used for delaying the retry.
   - parameter options: Options relevant to the scheduler’s behavior.
   - returns: A publisher that attempts to recreate its subscription to a failed upstream publisher.
   */
  func retry<S>(
    _ behavior: RetryBehavior<S>,
    shouldRetry: RetryPredicate? = nil,
    tolerance: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride? = nil,
    scheduler: S,
    options: S.SchedulerOptions? = nil
  ) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> where S: Scheduler {
    return retry(
      1,
      behavior: behavior,
      shouldRetry: shouldRetry,
      tolerance: tolerance,
      scheduler: scheduler,
      options: options
    )
  }
  
  private func retry<S>(
    _ currentAttempt: UInt,
    behavior: RetryBehavior<S>,
    shouldRetry: RetryPredicate? = nil,
    tolerance: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride? = nil,
    scheduler: S,
    options: S.SchedulerOptions? = nil
  ) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> where S: Scheduler {
    
    // This shouldn't happen, in case it does we finish immediately
    guard currentAttempt > 0 else { return Empty<Output, Failure>().eraseToAnyPublisher() }
    
    // Calculate the retry conditions
    let conditions = behavior.calculateConditions(currentAttempt)
    
    return self.catch { error -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> in
      
      // If we exceed the maximum retries we return the error
      guard currentAttempt <= conditions.maxRetries else {
        return Fail(error: error).eraseToAnyPublisher()
      }
      
      if let shouldRetry = shouldRetry, shouldRetry(error) == false {
        // If the shouldRetry predicate returns false we also return the error
        return Fail(error: error).eraseToAnyPublisher()
      }
      
      guard conditions.delay != .zero else {
        // If there is no delay, we retry immediately
        return self.retry(
          currentAttempt + 1,
          behavior: behavior,
          shouldRetry: shouldRetry,
          tolerance: tolerance,
          scheduler: scheduler,
          options: options
        )
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
      }
      
      // We retry after the specified delay
      return Just(()).delay(for: conditions.delay, tolerance: tolerance, scheduler: scheduler, options: options).flatMap {
        return self.retry(
          currentAttempt + 1,
          behavior: behavior,
          shouldRetry: shouldRetry,
          tolerance: tolerance,
          scheduler: scheduler,
          options: options
        )
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
      }
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
  
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! Have you tried it in production?

Comment: @Objectif yes it's working as expected

Answer (score 5):

Using `.catch` is indeed the answer. We simply make a reference to the data task publisher and use that reference as the head of both pipelines — the outer pipeline that does the initial networking, and the inner pipeline produced by the `.catch` function.

Let's start by creating the data task publisher *and stop*:

```
let pub = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url).share()
```

Now I can form the head of the pipeline:

```
let head = pub.catch {_ in pub.delay(for: 3, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)}
    .retry(3)
```

That should do it! `head` is now a pipeline that inserts a delay operator only just in case there is an error. We can then proceed to form the rest of the pipeline, based on `head`.

Observe that we do indeed change publishers; if there is a failure and the `catch` function runs, the `pub` which is the upstream of the `.delay` becomes the publisher, replacing the `pub` we started out with. However, they are the same object (because I said `share`), so this is a distinction without a difference.

Comment: When trying this in a playground it seems that the request is only sent once, so if it fails the request isn't attempted again. Am I holding it wrong or did something Change in Xcode 11.4.1?

Comment: @donnywals I don't know what you're actually doing, but I wouldn't try _anything_ in a playground. It sounds to me like you may have forgotten to `store` the pipeline? But that would be a different question; maybe ask a whole new question, showing your code...?

Comment: @donnywals I just tested again and it works fine. I put `.print("retrying").retry(3)` and sure enough, I see `"retrying"` three times (at three-second intervals) and then the failure arrives into the sink's completion handler. Let me know if you need to send you the complete code.

Comment: @matt The thing is, although the retrying happens, the request itself get sent only once however strange it may sound. I came across this problem in real app trying to implement your solution. Please, look at my question for the details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61782590/urlsession-datataskpublisher-retry-after-delay-on-specific-errors

Comment: I can try in an app but I definitely stored the pipeline and ran into the exact point @swasta mentioned. The retry is performed, but no request is made (which makes sense because you reuse the data task publisher which already fired and shares its result.) I do get a new request without the share but then I get extra requests like Heckj writes in his answer

Comment: @matt I actually came here due to swasta's question and the code shown there, so you can take a look at that if you want