# URLSession dataTaskPublisher retry after delay on specific errors

Tags: ios, swift, combine

What I'm trying to do is to resend a request for specific kinds of errors. Let's say for the timeout error specifically I want to retry the request after 3 seconds delay. Obviously, I don't want any delays if the request executed successfully.

I'm using the approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60637050/4933617)

```swift
var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!
let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 1
sessionConfiguration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData

let publisher = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration).dataTaskPublisher(for: url).share()

let head = publisher.print().tryCatch { error -> AnyPublisher<(data: Data, response: URLResponse), URLError> in
    switch error {
    case URLError.timedOut:
        print("I'm in URLError.timedOut case")
        return publisher.delay(for: 3, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main).eraseToAnyPublisher()

    default:
        print("I'm in default case")
        throw error
    }
}.retry(3)

head.map { data, response in
    return data
}.sink(receiveCompletion: {
    print("completion \($0)")
}, receiveValue: {
    print("value \($0)")
}).store(in: &cancellables)
```

For the test purpose I set 1 second timeout interval for the URLSession and throttle my network connection expecting to see 4 failed requests when the whole pipeline finishes in about 10 seconds. But what I actually see is just one failed request and printed completion with a failure after some time. To me it seems like I do return `publisher` from `tryCatch` operator every three seconds but for some reason it doesn't happen to send a new request.

What am I missing? Are there any alternative solutions to this problem?

UPDATED 14/05/2020

I added `print()` operator right before `tryCatch`, and some printing inside closure. What I see in console is this

```
receive subscription: (Multicast)
request unlimited
receive error: (URLError(_nsError: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."...))
I'm in URLError.timedOut case
receive subscription: (Multicast)
request unlimited
receive error: (URLError(_nsError: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." ...))
I'm in URLError.timedOut case
receive subscription: (Multicast)
request unlimited
receive error: (URLError(_nsError: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." ...))
I'm in URLError.timedOut case
receive subscription: (Multicast)
request unlimited
receive error: (URLError(_nsError: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." ...))
I'm in URLError.timedOut case
completion failure(Foundation.URLError(_nsError: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."...))
```

But what I see in my Charles http proxy is exactly one request, the one that's sent before retries

Comment: What's the completion error that's printed eventually? It looks like you might be getting a different error than `URLError.timedOut` in your `tryCatch`. Have you tried removing the `switch` and always returning a delayed publisher (just to see if that works because it should)

Comment: Thanks for the question! I added some printing, may be it will help. To me it looks perfectly fine except returning publisher from catch doesn't trigger a request. I've also tried simple `catch` instead of `tryCatch` without any switches, the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing and your problem appears to be on this line:

```
let publisher = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration).dataTaskPublisher(for: url).share()
```

By using `share()` you replay, or share the result of the data task publisher. So while your retry logic works fine, the result of the first request will be replayed every time. If you remove the `share()` a new request will be made in case of `URLError.timedOut`.

If you need the replay / sharing then you can add that after your `retry` so the data task publisher you create doesn't replay the result of the initial attempt.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question the idea is taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60637050/4933617 that's why I used share(). Simply removing the share() is not a solution, I'm afraid, since now it makes much more than 4 requests before completing the whole pipeline with timeout failure

Comment: Interesting, the request appears to be fired off twice for each attempt.

I do wonder how/why the solution in that answer works because it makes no sense with the `share` since that would prevent the same call from being made  by that specific data task publisher

Comment: I did a whole bunch of tinkering over the weekend and came up with a solution for this problem. I wrote it down on my blog: https://www.donnywals.com/retrying-a-network-request-with-a-delay-in-combine/