# Retry with delay in Swift Combine?

Tags: swift, delay, combine, retry-logic, publisher

Tried these "solutions":

[Combine framework retry after delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60624851/combine-framework-retry-after-delay)

https://www.donnywals.com/retrying-a-network-request-with-a-delay-in-combine/

But all of them doesn't work:

```
let retryCount = 3
let delay = 5

func requestOneTime() -> Future<(), Error> { ... }

requestOneTime()
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    .retryWithDelay(retries: retryCount, delay: delay, scheduler: DispatchQueue.global())
```

The result is always the same:

`Instance method 'delay(for:tolerance:scheduler:options:)' requires that 'DispatchObject' conform to 'Scheduler'`

or

`Instance method 'retryWithDelay(retries:delay:scheduler:)' requires that 'DispatchObject' conform to 'Scheduler'`

I even tried to retry `URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher` with delay - the result is the same too. Why nothing works? Is caused by a minimum supported version in the project (iOS 13)?

**UPDATED**

Figured out that this code doesn't work:

```
.retryWithDelay(retries: retryCount, delay: delay, scheduler: DispatchQueue.global())
```

but this code works:

```
.retryWithDelay(retries: retryCount, delay: 5, scheduler: DispatchQueue.global())
```

but if it is a typical type mismatch then how to declare `delay` variable of type `S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride` correctly?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, using the solution in the first link.

Comment: @Sweeper found out that this error is caused by type mismatch but I still don't know how to declare the variable of this type correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `DispatchQueue.global()` as the scheduler, then `S` is `DispatchQueue`, and so `S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride` is [`DispatchQueue.SchedulerTimeType.Stride`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/schedulertimetype/stride). **This is a struct declared in `DispatchQueue.SchedulerTimeType`, not `Int`.**

Incidentally, `DispatchQueue.SchedulerTimeType.Stride` conforms to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`. That's why passing `5` directly works, since `5` is an integer literal.

If you want to declare a named constant for the delay, explicitly statethe type `DispatchQueue.SchedulerTimeType.Stride`.

```
let delay: DispatchQueue.SchedulerTimeType.Stride = 5
```

Alternatively,

```
let delay: DispatchQueue.SchedulerTimeType.Stride = .seconds(5)
```

or keep `delay` as an `Int`, and pass `.seconds(delay)` instead.